# Finding NULL pointers in std vectors

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, null

I'm working with vectors and at some point there will be NULL entries; I want to erase all NULL occurrences within the given vectors. My approach so far is not working:

```
for(int i = sent_flit_list->size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
if(sent_flit_list[i] == NULL)
    sent_flit_list->erase(sent_flit_list[i]);

for(int i = sent_pkt_list->size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
if(sent_pkt_list[i] == NULL)
    sent_pkt_list->erase(sent_pkt_list[i]);
```

Where

```
vector<Flit*> *sent_flit_list;
vector<Packet*> *sent_pkt_list;
```

are the vectors. I have tried casting to a type (Flit*)NULL/(Flit*)0 but with no success.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "is not working"? What happens? How does it differ from what you wanted to happen?

Comment: IIRC, `vector::erase` takes an iterator, not a value, as a parameter.

Comment: @Gareth Gives an error such as error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found... I simply want to remove anything that points to NULL in those vectors.

Comment: You should really be using `remove` for this rather than looping explicitly. I think the immediate cause of your problem is that `sent_flit_list` and `sent_pkt_list` are *pointers to vectors*, not *vectors*, so that when you say e.g. `sent_pkt_list[i]` that indexing operation isn't what you think it is. (This is not the only problem with the code, but it's the one that's causing that error message.)

Comment: Another Hint which nobody mentioned so far, remove if this is wrong:
We should never erase elements and looping over the vector with out iterators. Because Suppose you have 2 values in `std::vector a` you iterate over the vector with indexing like you do, now erase value at position one, the 2 index is now wrong because the vector shrinked... Always use iterators (`it`) and use `it=a.erase(it)`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the [Erase-Remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) to remove elements based on a predicate from a container.

In your case:

```
// with a predicate
my_vec.erase(std::remove_if(begin(my_vec), end(my_vec), 
                           [](Flit* x) { return x == nullptr; }), 
             end(my_vec));

// with a value value
my_vec.erase(std::remove(begin(my_vec), end(my_vec), nullptr),
             end(my_vec));
```

Your current approach isn't working, because [vector::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) expects an iterator to an element of the vector and not a value of the stored type.

Frankly, what you are doing seems a little bit strange. You shouldn't store pointers, but values in containers. If you require `nullable` values, use a `Maybe` class such as `boost::optional`.

Comment: What's wrong with a vector of pointers? Or even smart pointers?

Comment: @Johan: Something like `boost::optional` will assert that it's initialized, unlike possible null-pointer problems. However, if you have large objects, such a `Maybe` class is not always an option.

Comment: @Johan: Nothing, in fact.  Sometimes, it is the right thing to do.  However, the OP is using a bit too many of them to be considered normal (a pointer to a vector of pointers, twice).  Granted, we don't know the exact situation, but the fact that the OP is using that much pointerage, combined with the fact that he is beginner enough to not even know about `std::remove`, indicates he is a little over-zealous about them, and probably doesn't need them at all.

Comment: But using `end()` iterator in `erase()` is illegal: all iterators supplied to `erase()` must be valid AND derefernceable.

Answer (score 5):

`pmr` is absolutely correct that you should be using `remove` followed by `erase`, and that this is the most important mistake in the code. However, the mistake that's actually causing the error message you report is as follows:

Your variables `sent_pkt_list` and `sent_flit_list` are *pointers to vectors*, not *vectors*. Therefore, when you say something like `sent_pkt_list[i]`, this is doing C-style array indexing, not vector indexing. The value of `sent_pkt_list[i]` is a (doubtless nonsensical because it's effectively dereferencing a bogus pointer) `vector<Packet*>`, not a `Packet*`. So you then try to compare that against `NULL`, which of course doesn't work.

Comment: Personally, I think pmr's answer should have the upvotes (because, really, it's what the questioner needs to know) and mine should be accepted (because it happens to explain the specific error the questioner was troubled by). But life's too short to worry about whether any given SO answer has been treated exactly optimally by the voting-and-accepting public!

Answer (score 0):

```
// Full example for people who can have something equal to explained task and avoid read tones of discussions.

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct Flit {};
struct Packet {};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Flit*> sent_flit_list_(10);
    std::vector<Packet*> sent_pkt_list_(20);

    std::vector<Flit*> *sent_flit_list = &sent_flit_list_;
    std::vector<Packet*> *sent_pkt_list = &sent_pkt_list_;

    sent_flit_list->erase(std::remove(sent_flit_list->begin(),sent_flit_list->end(), nullptr), sent_flit_list->end());
    sent_pkt_list->erase(std::remove(sent_pkt_list->begin(),sent_pkt_list->end(), nullptr), sent_pkt_list->end());
    return 0;
}
```